# Assigning a priority value to objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, foreach

I have a Node JS program, where I need to assign 'priority' to different objects based on their CPU values. So I store all of the objects in an array, and sort this array based on increasing CPU values.

My array looks like this (the cpu values constantly change):

```
var lowerThan95 = [{
    'myname': 'abc',
    'CPU': 10
}, {
    'myname': 'gfd',
    'CPU': 45
}, {
    'myname': 'vfd',
    'CPU': 100
}, {
    'myname': 'bvf',
    'CPU': 80
}]
```

So the lowest CPU value should have a priority of 1, the second lowest priority of 2 etc. My thoughts are to add in a 'priority' attribute, and then go through every element in the array and add one to the priority each time. However how do I achieve this?

This is what I tried so far:

```
// sorts the array based on ascending cpu values
lowerThan95.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.CPU) - parseFloat(b.CPU);
});

// what do I do here?
lowerThan95.forEach(function(value) {
    var priority = priority + 1
    console.log('pr', priority)
});
```

Is this the right approach? Is there a better way to do this? Any help/tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need the priority on the object? If it's sorted, the priority is always the `length - index`

Comment: In your case `priority == index` so you need just index of an element in array to have priority

Comment: As others stated, you don't actually need the priority. However, your sorting is not working. Where does `average_cpu` suddenly come from?

Comment: @Connum corrected

Comment: @tymeJV what do you mean by that? Sorry im new into coding

Comment: @noDe1 - Basically, if your sort is working - the priority is easy to figure out on the fly (there's no reason to actually add it to the object) - it will always be the length of the array - index of the object in the array - `arr.length - index`

Comment: Well, to be fair - we don't know what the OP wants to do with those objects later on in the script. Maybe he/she has good reason to have a 1-based priority property that can later be used when processing those objects. That's why I decided to post an answer for his needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your sorting, you'll have to use `a.CPU` and `b.CPU`. Then, you can iterate over your sorted array and set the prioroty property like this:

```js
var lowerThan95 = [{
    'myname': 'abc',
    'CPU': 10
}, {
    'myname': 'gfd',
    'CPU': 45
}, {
    'myname': 'vfd',
    'CPU': 100
}, {
    'myname': 'bvf',
    'CPU': 80
}]

// sorts the array based on ascending cpu values
lowerThan95.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.CPU) - parseFloat(b.CPU);
});

// what do I do here?
for (var i in lowerThan95) {
  lowerThan95[i].priority = +i+1;
};

console.log(lowerThan95);
```

This answer does not use ECMA6 arrow functions in order to be compatible with Internet Explorer and older Android/iOS Browser versions.

Answer (score 0):

After you sort array you can use `forEach` loop to assign priority as each `index + 1`

```js
var lowerThan95 = [{
  'myname': 'abc',
  'CPU': 10
}, {
  'myname': 'gfd',
  'CPU': 45
}, {
  'myname': 'vfd',
  'CPU': 100
}, {
  'myname': 'bvf',
  'CPU': 80
}]
lowerThan95.sort((a, b) => a.CPU - b.CPU).forEach((e, i) => e.priority = (i + 1))

console.log(lowerThan95)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lowerThan95.map(function(obj,index) {
    obj["priority"]=lowerThan95.length-index;
    return obj;
});
```

As you can see, as others pointed out, this code is quite senseless as every priority is length minus index. If you really want to count up:

```
lowerThan95.reduce((val,obj)=>obj.priority= ++val,0);
```